# Hidden upload form don't register the change event in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I refactoring my upload form. Want to have this  fancy photo icon and now don't work.
Before I have this code and everything works fine:

```html
<div class="row user-profile">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img class="img-responsive" *ngIf="userApi.path" src="{{createImgPath(userApi.path)}}" />
            <img class="img-responsive" *ngIf="!userApi.path" src="{{createImgPath(usersImages/userApi.user.imageUrl)}}" />
                <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div id="upload">
                        <label class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                            Browse<input (change)="uploadPhoto()" #fileInput class="btn btn-back" type="file" name="photo" style="display:none" />
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </form>
        </div>
```

I remove label element and add icon photo element and also all that I wrapped in to div element with class edit. This is my code in html:

```html
<div class="col-md-4 profile-pic">
            <img class="img-responsive" *ngIf="userApi.path" src="{{createImgPath(userApi.path)}}" />
            <img class="img-responsive" *ngIf="!userApi.path" src="{{createImgPath(usersImages/userApi.user.imageUrl)}}" />
            <div class="edit"> 
                <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <i class="material-icons">
                            photo_camera 
                        </i>
                        <input (change)="uploadPhoto()" #fileInput  type="file" name="photo" style="display:none" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

In css file I hide upload form and show the photo icon in hover. This is my css file:

```css
 .profile-pic:hover .edit {
        display: block;
    }
    
    .edit {
        position: absolute;
        right: 25;
        top: 0;
        display: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .edit i{
        background-color:rgba(218, 213, 213, 0.884);
        border: 1px solid bleck;
        color: grey;
        border-radius: 50%;
        padding: 5px;
    }
```

In my ts file I have method uploadPhoto. This is in my ts file:

```js
@ViewChild('fileInput',{static: true}) fileInput: ElementRef;
 uploadPhoto(){
    var nativeElement:HTMLInputElement =  this.fileInput.nativeElement;
    this.userApi.upload(nativeElement.files[0]);
  }
```

When I want to click the input (photo icon) nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to wrap your icon and text into label and change the code like this

`<label for="uploadIcon">
   <i class="material-icons">
       photo_camera 
   </i>
   <input (change)="uploadPhoto()" #fileInput id="uploadIcon"  type="file" name="photo" style="display:none" />
</label>`

Comment: Thank you @dhananjay bhirud

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried surrounding your input-element with your i-element, same way as the label-element used to be?

Comment: and adding a click-event on your icon to trigger the input is not an option?